# Why invariant subspaces are important?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

My teacher says that to study a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ is equivalent to study $T|_{U_{i}}$, where $U_i$ are invariant subspaces of $V$.

Why so? I cant understand. Please help to understand

Comment: What he's saying is (at least for finite-dimensional spaces) basically that we can change basis of $U$ so that the matrix that represents $T$ in that basis is block diagonal (preferably with as small blocks as possible), then study those blocks.

Answer (score 3):

For instance:

- $T$ is invertible if and only if each $T|_{U_i}$ is invertible;
- $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if each $T|_{U_i}$ is diagonalizable.

But the $U_i$'s are smaller spaces. Therefore, it easier (in general) to study each $T|_{U_i}$ than the whole transformation $T$.